# SQL Query - add records to all categories

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with this data:

```
ID       ENTRYID      ORDERID     NAME       VALUE
-----------------------------------------------------
1        123          1           Product    AAA
2        123          1           Product    BBB
3        123          2           Type       Consumer
4        123          3           Category   Device
5        123          4           Vendor     CompanyName
```

The ENTRYID is the value to identify the related rows (group of entries).

I need the data in the following format:

```
Product        Name              Value
-------------------------------------------
AAA            Type              Consumer
AAA            Category          Device
AAA            Vendor            CompanyName
BBB            Type              Consumer
BBB            Category          Device
BBB            Vendor            CompanyName
```

So basically from the group of entries above foreach Product where `ORDERID = 1` or `NAME = Product` I need to add the other details. So in this case products are AAA and BBB and for each of them we add the Type, Category and Vendor. There can be one or more product for each group of entry with same ENTRYID.

I tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
     CASE WHEN NAME = 'Product' THEN Value END AS PRODUCT,
     …
FROM MYTABLE
```

It gives me the products in one column but are listed only twice

```
PRODUCT 
---------------
AAA
BBB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in your sample data, I think this query will do what you want. It selects all the `Product` values for a given `ENTRYID`, and then `JOIN`s those to all the non-product values for that `ENTRYID`:

```
SELECT P.VALUE AS Product, N.NAME AS Name, N.VALUE AS Value
FROM (SELECT ENTRYID, VALUE
      FROM test
      WHERE NAME = 'Product') P
JOIN (SELECT ENTRYID, NAME, VALUE
      FROM test
      WHERE NAME != 'Product') N ON N.ENTRYID = P.ENTRYID
```

Output:

```
Product     Name        Value
AAA         Type        Consumer
AAA         Category    Device
AAA         Vendor      CompanyName
BBB         Type        Consumer
BBB         Category    Device
BBB         Vendor      CompanyName
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=16a8c895a3439df6ac9c1f37bb650ccb)